# Why a Firebase Function is blocked by CORS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, cors

Accessing *my* `Function` *from my own domain*, the function WILL work, but client get an error that it was blocked by CORS.

```
 exports.registerNewUser = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
```

and I call it with :

```
 var url = "https://us-central1-xxxxxxxx.cloudfunctions.net/registerNewUser";
       $.get(
               url,
               {email : email, userid:userID},
               function(data){ ....
```

I was asking this question a while ago, and **i found out that wrapping the function content** with this , solves it :

```
cors(req, res, () => {
```

I couldn't see anyone doing it, I wonder if/why do I really need this, because the docs never mention something like it. ( function will fire but will never send respond)

**Executing this Function link from the browser works perfect.**

Comment: Actually the docs mention it, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events?authuser=0#use_middleware_modules_with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're observing is expected, and [documented](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events?authuser=0#use_middleware_modules_with).  By default, you can't access a function from a domain other than the one of your loaded web page.  This is a security feature that all browsers implement.  It prevents malicious code from working outside of the boundary of its web domain.  That's why [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) is necessary - to allow these cross-domain requests to occur explicitly.

Comment: Thanks Doug. "you can't access a function from a domain other than the one of your loaded web page" - well, as i said, i am accessing it from my own domain that I registered in Firebase, this is why it is still weird that CORS are stopping me.

Comment: The browser doesn't know anything about domain ownership.  It is just looking at the name of the domain where the web page was loaded and comparing that to the domain where the API is hosted.  If the names don't match exactly, then the browser will reject the request, and you need to enable CORS.